# VMware cannot share USB flash drive with Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 18.04, vmware

I am using VMware Workstation Player and Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I want to share my USB flash Drive from Windows to Ubuntu but It does not show up.

[image]

With Ubuntu Desktop I can easily share the USB flash drive to Ubuntu, and I can access it using `/media/usbxxxxxx`

But I can't do it with Ubuntu Server.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why not use virtualbox? setting that up on virtualbox is a breeze. also you're asking a VMware question, not an ubuntu question : https://communities.vmware.com/welcome would have been the right place to ask, not here.

Comment: virtualbox is not an option as I've been working on VMware for quite long

Comment: Windows is off-topic here.  The question is about getting USB working for Ubuntu guest in a Windows host application.  The answer below will not help Ubuntu users that use VMPlayer in Ubuntu as those settings do not exist.  This question is better suited for https://superuser.com

Comment: Do you have a USB controller in the virtual hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by manually enabling the VMware USB Arbitration Service which was disabled

[image]